# CP : How is runtime and memory used in calculated in leetcode

Tags: memory, runtime

So i was solving this problem https://leetcode.com/problems/can-place-flowers/?envType=study-plan-v2&envId=leetcode-75 (Can place flowers )
and my solution for the same is below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMmtA.png)
image for soln 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUCs4.png)
image for soln2

as you can see in both images there is only one condition difference which is if(ans == n) and updated condition is if(ans >= n)
So with just changing this conditioning how does my memory and runtime beats vary that much

I tried different condition and wants to know how is this being calculated

Comment: Why not ask this the people of LeetCode? They should be able to tell you how they configure their servers and calculate these metrics. But running the same code multiple times already shows there can be differences in time and memory, so you should not focus on that too much.

Comment: Do not tag this as `dsa`.  The `dsa` tag is for `Digital Signature Algorithm`.  Also do not tag `cp` as that is for the UNIX copy command.  Please read the descriptions of the tags you are using before applying them to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer here.

https://leetcode.com/discuss/general-discussion/1387332/Can-someone-explain-how-machine-checks-runtime-and-memory-usage/1038636

Also don't bother about runtime or memory usage on leetcode, just make sure you know the space and time complexity of your code and try to improve that.
I have had instances with 0 ms for the worst solutions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).